# I have date stored in a string, go one day back

Tags: php

I have a date stored in a variable:

```
$date = '2017-06-01';
```

And I want to go `one` day back. So in this case, the variable should end up being:

```
$date = '2017-05-31';
```

What's the appropriate way to go "one day back" in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of PHPs [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.sub.php) class gives a perfect example for what you ask. You just would have to read it...

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2017-06-01');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d'));
```

The output obviously is:

```
string(10) "2017-05-31"
```

Comment: great solution !!

Answer (score 1):

Here we are using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) for achieving desired output.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/791327)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$noOfDays=1;//no of days to subtract

$date = '2017-06-01';
$dateTime= new DateTime($date);
$result=$dateTime->sub(new DateInterval("P".$noOfDays."D"));//subtracting date by $noOfDays days
print_r($result->format("Y-m-d"));//returning specific format of date.
```

**Output:**
`2017-05-31`

Answer (score 0):

here  strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($date) subtract 1 day from given date & the convert into date with date function with given format :

```
<?php
$date = '2017-06-01';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($date)))
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.